# Many to many in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, relationship

How to write model in ember with many to many relation like this?

Patron

- hasMany Events (as Events patron go)
- belongTo Event (as who attend the Event)

Event

- belongTo Patron (as what event patron go)
- hasMany Patron (as Event attendees)

currently i write it like this, is this correct?

Event

```
export default DS.Model.extend({      
  patron: DS.belongsTo('patron', {    
    async:true,
    inverse: 'events'
  }),
  attendees: DS.hasMany('patron', {    
    async:true,
    inverse: 'attending'
  }),
})
```

Patron

```
export default DS.Model.extend({      
  events: DS.hasMany('event', {
    inverse: null
    async: true
  }),
  attending: belongsTo('event', {
    async: true,
    inverse: 'attendees'
  })
})
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be more appropriate for this.

Comment: As long as it works it is correct.